# How to log using custom metric in GCP Cloud Composer using python?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I want to log message with custom metric in google cloud composer's DAG.
Assume that this metric is some number.

This will allow me to write rule/policy with some threshold and further send email.

Could you please provide python snippet to log with custom metric?

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Have you tried to do this yourself?

Comment: I tried, however unable get API to pass custom metric.

Comment: If you include your best attempt, people might be able to help you.

Comment: Consider using the Airflow PythonOperator, along with the `google-cloud-monitoring` package.